# Want to clone a role, but am getting "can't login" message after doing so

Tags: postgresql, permissions, duplication, role

I’m using Postgres 9.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I would like to create a role (user) that has all the same privileges and access to a database that an existing role in my system has.  I thought I could pull that off by creating that user and then granting the other role to him…

```
postgres=# create role myuser;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# GRANT rails TO myuser;
GRANT ROLE
```

but then when I login to that user, it turns out I don’t even have login privileges.

```
myuser@myproject:~$ psql mydb_production
psql: FATAL:  role "myuser" is not permitted to log in
```

What is the proper way to clone a role to another user (e.g. copy the privileges)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html) is simple, but may be very surprising:

> `CREATE USER` is now an alias for `CREATE ROLE`. The only difference is
>   that when the command is spelled `CREATE USER`, `LOGIN` is assumed by
>   default, whereas `NOLOGIN` is assumed when the command is spelled 
>   `CREATE ROLE`.

So use `CREATE USER` instead of `CREATE ROLE`.

There is one more equally tricky aspect of this. Even if the role you grant to the new role (in your example, `rails`) has the `LOGIN` option, `myuser` won't inherit it.  The reason is that `GRANT` only gives *permissions*, while `LOGIN` is an *attribute* of the user/role:

```
CREATE USER rails; -- means it has LOGIN
CREATE ROLE myuser;
GRANT rails TO myuser;

\du rails
           List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of 
-----------+------------+-----------
 rails     |            | {}

\du myuser  
            List of roles
 Role name |  Attributes  | Member of 
-----------+--------------+-----------
 myuser    | Cannot login | {rails}
```

**Note:** if you are using one of the `trust` and `peer` authentication methods in `pg_hba.conf`, it's possibly a good idea to rethink that.  If you are using LDAP (the last idea I have, given that you don't specify a password), then ignore this.

Comment: But if the role `rails` is allowed to log in, shouldn't `grant rails to myuser` allow myuser to log in as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good question, see my edit.